# How to obtain a list of all markers in matplotlib?

Tags: python, matplotlib, markers

The diagrams I am generating have many lines, and I want to automatically use colors and markers to distinguish them.

I tried this:

```
for i,studyDframeTuple in enumerate(studyDframeTuples):
    time  = studyDframeTuple[1]['time']
    error = studyDframeTuple[1]['Linf velocity error']
    caseName = studyDirs[studyDframeTuple[0]]
    ax.plot(time, error, marker = i % 12, label=caseName)
```

Which circulates `marker` over (0,11). This kind of works, because for some reason `marker < 12`. When I use `marker = i % 20`, I get an error that `makerstyle 12 is unknown`.

This is an example of the diagram I'm generating, it's not pretty, it's only used for checking test results:

[image]

The diagrams are resulting from tests with varying parameters, hence the need to iterate over all available colors, line styles and markers, to make sure that when I have 100 lines on a diagram, I can distinguish the ones that belong to exploded solutions (values like 1e15 on this plot).

How can I put all markers in matplotib in a list and iterate over them?

**Edit**:

I hacked a list of my own like this

```
mStyles = [".",",","o","v","^","<",">","1","2","3","4","8","s","p","P","*","h","H","+","x","X","D","d","|","_",0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11
]
```

But what when this changes? Can I obtain this list programmatically from matplotlib?

Comment: I found a list of all markers and their "tag_ID" [Here](https://matplotlib.org/3.1.1/api/markers_api.html?highlight=marker#module-matplotlib.markers) and 12 isn't in the list

Answer (score 17, accepted):

12 doesn't exist as marker value. You can have a dict of all existing markers using this :

```py
from matplotlib.lines import Line2D
print(Line2D.markers)
```

Output:

```py
{'.': 'point',
 ',': 'pixel',
 'o': 'circle',
 'v': 'triangle_down',
 '^': 'triangle_up',
 '<': 'triangle_left',
 '>': 'triangle_right',
 '1': 'tri_down',
 '2': 'tri_up',
 '3': 'tri_left',
 '4': 'tri_right',
 '8': 'octagon',
 's': 'square',
 'p': 'pentagon',
 '*': 'star',
 'h': 'hexagon1',
 'H': 'hexagon2',
 '+': 'plus',
 'x': 'x',
 'D': 'diamond',
 'd': 'thin_diamond',
 '|': 'vline',
 '_':'hline',
 'P': 'plus_filled',
 'X': 'x_filled',
 0: 'tickleft',
 1: 'tickright',
 2: 'tickup',
 3:'tickdown',
 4: 'caretleft',
 5: 'caretright',
 6: 'caretup',
 7: 'caretdown',
 8: 'caretleftbase',
 9: 'caretrightbase',
 10: 'caretupbase',
 11: 'caretdownbase',
 'None': 'nothing',
 None: 'nothing',
 ' ': 'nothing',
 '': 'nothing'}
```